# Directory changes after opening certain files

Tags: vim, osx-mavericks

**EDIT**

The scenario changed. Sorry, for posting question a bit too early.

When opening a file (`vim filename.ext`, or `:e filename.txt`, etc.), when the CWD is `~/Sites/A`, vim changes to another CWD (`~/Sites/B`).

I found out, that vim does this because of a file in my `~/.vim/view/` folder, called `~=+Sites=+B=+src=+filename.txt=`.

The file inside `~/.vim/view/` contains:

```
let s:so_save = &so | let s:siso_save = &siso | set so=0 siso=0
argglobal
setlocal fdm=manual
setlocal fde=0
setlocal fmr={{{,}}}
setlocal fdi=#
setlocal fdl=0
setlocal fml=1
setlocal fdn=20
setlocal fen
silent! normal! zE
let s:l = 200 - ((13 * winheight(0) + 11) / 23)
if s:l < 1 | let s:l = 1 | endif
exe s:l
normal! zt
200
normal! 030|
lcd ~/Sites/B
let &so = s:so_save | let &siso = s:siso_save
doautoall SessionLoadPost
" vim: set ft=vim :
```

Why is the line `lcs ~/Sites/B` standing in this file? Inside `~/Sites/B` never existed a file called `filename.ext`.

**For the sake of completeness, this is my question, before I localized the error:**

When i vimgrep something in a codebase located in `~/Sites/a` (e.g. `:vimgrep DateCell src/**/*`) vim's current working directory changes to another directory `~/Sites/B`.

Every subsequent call to `vimgrep` or another working-directory-aware-command fails or returns wrong results, because it is operating in the `~/Sites/B` directory.

What could cause this?

What I do, to achieve the error / wrong behaviour:

1. `cd ~/Sites/A`
2. `vim`
3. `vimgrep something src/**/*`
4. `:!pwd` shows `~/Sites/B`
5. `:quit`
6. `pwd` shows `~/Sites/A`

**EDIT**

It turns out, that the directory change also happens if I don't use `vimgrep`. I still don't know what produces the error.

BTW: It is always the same directory (`~/Sites/B`), vim changes to. No matter in which directory i am working.

Vim Version: 8.0.2
OS Version: OS X 10.10.5

Comment: It happens, when I open a file with NERDTree. But not always. On some files, only.

Comment: `vimgrep` isn't doing this, as you've noticed; may want to update the question title. It's likely that some plugin you're using is doing this, or you have a `cd` or `lcd` somewhere in your `.vimrc`. Try eliminating plugins to identify the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I deactivated all plugins, except NERDTree. Issue remains. I found out, that the cause is NOT as described in my question. But when opening a file from NERDTree. What shall I do with the wrong question? Anyone an idea? Changing the title won't be enough. Shall I vote for delete and create a new question?

Comment: I ditched NERDTree in favor of the built-in netrw so I don't have my config handy, but check out `:help NERDTreeChDirMode`. There are other questions on Stack Overflow and Super User discussing it. This question is probably a duplicate of one of those but I'll leave that to you to determine.

Comment: Found out more, NERDTree is not the cause. Changed my question.

Comment: You may find [this explanation](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5) useful.

Answer (score 0):

The `~=+Sites=+B=+src=+filename.txt=` is a saved *view* for `~/Sites/B/src/filename.txt`. The question is: Why does it get loaded when you open a file (with the same name, or any, not entirely clear from your question) from another directory?

Normally, views have to be created and restored manually. You seem to have something in your configuration (`:autocmd`) that *automatically* restores saved views, and that something has a bug in its path lookup (or, less likely, your filesystem is messed up and you have symlinks there). Find that, and turn it off / fix it.